# Why is pandas df.add_suffix() not working with for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, suffix

I am trying to use pandas `df.add_suffix()` for multiple dataframes, that are stored in a list via a for-loop:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [2, 3, 4, 5],  'Y': [4, 5, 6, 7]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [6, 7, 8, 9],  'Y': [9, 8, 7, 6]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [6, 3, 1, 13],  'Y': [7, 0, 1, 4]})

mylist = [df_1, df_2, df_3]

for i in mylist:
    i = i.add_suffix('_test')
```

However when I print the dataframes afterwards, i see still the old column names "X" and "Y".

When doing the same operation on each of the dataframes separately:

```
df1 = df_1.add_suffix('_test')
```

everything works as expected and I get the column names "X_test" and "Y_test".

Does anyone have any idea, what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are changing the value of the variable `i` but `i` it is not the same with the `mylist` elements, when you are iterating using `for` loop you are assigning to the variable `i` consecutive elements from `mylist`, you should use the list index to change the elements:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = mylits[i].add_suffix('_test')
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is output is no assign back to list, so no change.

Solution if want assign to same list of `DataFrame`s with `enumerate` for indexing:

```
for j,i in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[j] = i.add_suffix('_test')

print (mylist)
[   X_test  Y_test
0       2       4
1       3       5
2       4       6
3       5       7,    X_test  Y_test
0       6       9
1       7       8
2       8       7
3       9       6,    X_test  Y_test
0       6       7
1       3       0
2       1       1
3      13       4]
```

Or if want new list of `DataFrame`s use list comprehension:

```
dfs = [i.add_suffix('_test') for i in mylist]

print (dfs)
[   X_test  Y_test
0       2       4
1       3       5
2       4       6
3       5       7,    X_test  Y_test
0       6       9
1       7       8
2       8       7
3       9       6,    X_test  Y_test
0       6       7
1       3       0
2       1       1
3      13       4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [2, 3, 4, 5],  'Y': [4, 5, 6, 7]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [6, 7, 8, 9],  'Y': [9, 8, 7, 6]})
df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'X': [6, 3, 1, 13],  'Y': [7, 0, 1, 4]})

mylist = [df_1, df_2, df_3]

for i,j in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = j.add_suffix('_test')
```

The updated dfs are in the list(mylist) rather than the original one.